# What don't we know about cancer?

Tags: cancer

I was wondering, after decades of research what we do not know about Cancer yet as in what unanswered questions are still puzzling biologists about cancer?

I have read that cancer research, in its modern form, is a [quest](https://medicalxpress.com/news/2018-04-ageing-cancer-scientists-unveil-immortality.html) for [biological immortality](http://berkeleysciencereview.com/article/chasing-immortality/). Does this hold any truth?

Answer (score 2):

I think this thread will become a jungle very fast and very soon, so I suggest you to have a look at the cancer research reviews of the last 2 years to get a grasp. Have a look at *cancer hallmarks* and at other important key concepts, you will most certainly answer your question yourself :) I am not a cancer researcher so I cannot comment on the topic in a detailed fashion (I work on plants), but that's what's going to happen.

In general, I'd say that what we don't know about cancer is a "common ancestor" of all types of it that will enable us to tailor a one-sized cure.